# How to save values when using checkbox and countrylist in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I can't seem to save my values (checkbox and country list) to the table. I need help to improve my logic below, meaning they appear as NULL from the table on my database? What needs to change based on the given logic? I want if I select e.g Halaal and Vegetarian both should show from the table within the database the same applies with countryList(Afhaganistan/Ghana).

```
    // Controller for CountryList
     private List<RegistrationTrainingForm> LoadData()
            {
                List<RegistrationTrainingForm> lst = new List<RegistrationTrainingForm>();
    
                try
                {
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    string srcFilePath = "Content/files/country_list.txt";
                    var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
                    string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
                    StreamReader src = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    
                    // while to read the file
                    while ((line = src.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        RegistrationTrainingForm infoLst = new RegistrationTrainingForm();
                        string[] info = line.Split(',');
    
                        //Setting
                        infoLst.Country_Id = Convert.ToInt32(info[0].ToString());
                        infoLst.Country_Name = info[1].ToString();
    
                        lst.Add(infoLst);
                    }
                    src.Dispose();
                    src.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex);
                }
                return lst;
            }
    
    
            // List for countries.
            private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountryList()
            {
                SelectList listcn = null;
                try
                {
                    var list = this.LoadData().Select(p => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = p.Country_Id.ToString(),
                        Text = p.Country_Name
                    });
                    listcn = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                return listcn;
            }


// Controller to SaveChanges to DB.
 //GET:TrainingRegForm/Create/WebRequest.
        [HttpPost]
       
        public ActionResult SubmitRegDetails(RegViewAndRoleViewModel eNtsaRegistration)
        {
           

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               
                db.TrainingRegs.Add(eNtsaRegistration.RegForm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("SaveRegForm");
            }

            // Validates when empty.
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SaveRegForm");
            }
            return View(eNtsaRegistration);
        }

    
    // Model for both Checkbox and CountryList
    public class DietViewModel
        {
    
            [Display(Name = "None")]
    
            [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
            public bool None { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Vegetarian")]
    
            [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
    
            public bool Vegetarian { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Vegan")]
    
            [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
            public bool Vegan { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Halaal")]
    
            [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
            public bool Halaal { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Other")]
    
            [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
            public bool Other { get; set; }
    
    
        }
     public class DropDownViewModel
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
            public string LastName { get; set; }
    
            public string Position { get; set; }
    
            public string Company { get; set; }
    
            public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    
            public string StreetAddressLine { get; set; }
    
            public string City { get; set; }
    
            public string State { get; set; }
    
            public string Country { get; set; }
    
            public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    
            public string Email { get; set; }
    
            public int CellNumber { get; set; }
    
            public string DietaryRequirements { get; set; }
    
            public int Country_Id { get; set; }
    
            public string Country_Name { get; set; }
        }
    
    // View for both CountryList and Checkbox
    <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dietary requirements:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.None, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.DietMain.None)">None</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.DietMain.Vegetarian)">Vegetarian</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegan, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m=>m.DietMain.Vegan)">Vegan</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Halaal, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m=>m.DietMain.Halaal)">Halaal</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Other, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m=>m.DietMain.Other)">Other</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListCountries.Country, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList)
                                </div>
```

Comment: Are you able to actually post the selected values to the server?  Can you show the whole form markup, and the controller you're posting to, please?

Comment: @Jamie i have posted whole form, no i can only select the country and checkBox, but to these the selected values, they dont get saved from the table within the DB.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to save to the database please?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  If you debug SubmitRegDetails, are the selected values in the eNtsaRegistration object?